# WCF REST gives 404 on IIS but wsdl is working

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, iis, http-status-code-404

I got a WCF REST web service on IIS 7.5.

I can view the wsdl-file by entering `http://site/webservice.svc`, but if I try `http://site/webservice/help`, I get a 404 error. 
This 404 error also occurs for all function calls, both GET and POST.

This webservice is working perfectly well in other environments with the exact same files and web.config, so I wonder if there might be any wrong configuration in IIS?

Binding is this:

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="rest">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: **REST** services don't typically have a WSDL, and if you have a WSDL, then it's typically a **SOAP** web service you're talking about.... so what **WCF binding** is your service using? Look at the server-side config for that service.

Comment: Added bindings. But as I said, this is working in other environments with the same web.config.

Comment: Added complete binding.

Comment: If you have a WCF REST service, you should see "There is a web service here" type of response when you browse to http://site/webservice.svc and not a wsdl interface. When you debug in Visual Studio (before publishing to IIS), do you still see a wsdl interface?? If you do, then you are not constructing your WCF REST service correctly.